# Can I call function in previous screen - react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a function "signInWithPhoneNumber" in **SignUp** screen after call it navigates me to a **Confirmation** Screen and I pass some params after navigate to confirm a verification code I was received,
So in this screen "Confirmation", I have a button "Re-send Verification Code" so my question is 
when I press to "re-send" I want to call a "signInWithPhoneNumber" function in SignUp screen to get a new code

So what you think? that's possible?

Or rewrite a ***signInWithPhoneNumber*** in a confirmation screen and call it after pressed re-send button?

**SignUp Screen - Function**

```
  signUp = async () => {

    const {phoneNumber} = this.state;
    this.setState({message: 'Sending code ...'});
    const phoneWithAreaCode = phoneNumber.replace(/^0+/, '+972');
    console.log(phoneWithAreaCode);
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode, true)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        console.log('confirmResult', confirmResult);
        this.setState({confirmResult, message: 'Code has been sent!'});
        // this.createUserDatabase();
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Confirmation', {
          message: this.state.message,
          confirmResult: this.state.confirmResult,
          createUser: uid => this.createUserDatabase(uid),
        });
      });
  };
```

**Confirmation screen - function**

```
confirmCode = codeInput => {

    const confirmResult = this.props.navigation.state.params.confirmResult

    if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
      confirmResult
        .confirm(codeInput)
        .then(user => {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
          //Check if any users exist
          database()
            .ref(`users`)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .once('value', snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log('exists!');
                return true;
              } else {
                params.createUser(user.uid);
                console.log('No user found Hah');
              }
            });
          this.setState({
            timer: 0,
            message: 'Code Confirmed!',
            isValid: true,
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          let errorCode = error.code;
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);
          switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
              this.setState({message: 'Code is invalid', codeInput: ''});
              this.refs.codeInputRef2.clear();
              break;
            default:
              alert(`Please, Check your Messages!`);
              break;
          }
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Not here');
    }
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the functton to the other screen?

Comment: Which function?

Comment: The signInWithPhoneNumber. Include it in the navigate parameters and use it in the other screen.

Comment: try to create global function of signInWithPhoneNumber which can be called from any screen, just pass the parameter to function, and it will execute .

Comment: But i rely on confirmResult that's coming from params when navigate to confirmation screen , so how can i handle it if make it global as @vijayKahar said and @ GamingRuru if want to include it as params

Comment: @DevAS exectly you have to pass values as parameter in your global function

Comment: @vijaykahar Hmm, Can you write an example of code in the answers, I think I misunderstood you :/

Comment: Create a file which contains global functions, and import it in the screen where you want to use it.

Comment: i have created a file name util in utility folder, so i import the file as ```import * as utility from '../../Utility/util';```

Comment: Now simply call the function as ```utility.functionName(yourparameters)```.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `signInWithPhoneNumber` to `Confirmation` screen, while navigating to it from `SignUp` screen, like so

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Confirmation', {
          message: this.state.message,
          confirmResult: this.state.confirmResult,
          createUser: uid => this.createUserDatabase(uid),

          signInWithPhoneNumber: signInWithPhoneNumber // your actual function here
        });
      });
```

And then this function will be available in `Confirmation` screen as a prop, and you can call it when necessary

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't use redux sadly

Comment: You need not use redux for this. Just pass the function to the next screen as mentioned in the code snippet

Comment: that's ok but as you see  i rely on confirmResul in confirmCode() function, so as you said if i pass it as params and call it in a separate button it will give me a new confirmResul that's not a last one i have in confirmCode()